# Cannot read property onSubmit of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Trying to pass down a function as a prop:

```
import {
...
} from "react-native";

import {
...
} from "../actions/events";

import { isLoading, isLoadingCredentials, hasErrored } from "../actions/loader";

class HomeScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "",
        headerMode: "screen",
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {
            navigation: { navigate },
            setCredentials
        } = this.props;
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        const {
            ...
        } = this.props;

        if (!authenticated) {
            return <Login onPress={this.onAuthenticate} />;
        }

        return (

                <View
                    style={styles.container}
                    onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}
                >

                    <Pickers
                        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                    />
                </View>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        categories: state.fetchCategories,
        isLoading: state.isLoading,
        hasErrored: state.hasErrored,
        credentials: state.setCredentials,
        isLoadingCredentials: state.isLoadingCredentials,
        authenticated: state.authenticated
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  ....
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen);
```

Child:

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Picker from "./common/Picker";
import {
..
} from "react-native";

import {
...
} from "../actions/events";

export class Pickers extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      credentials: { year, group, student, showStudent }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit()}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Submit</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    credentials: state.setCredentials
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
...
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Pickers);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    return <TouchableHighlight
           onClick={this.props.onSubmit} 
            />
}
```

Your `onSubmit` method is being passed from the Props not on the class.
So it is undefined.
Hence You need to call `this.props.onSubmit` while submitting.
It will call the function which is passed as the `prop` from your Parent Component.

And yeah now you should switch to the `ES6` syntax.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "",
        headerMode: "screen",
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onSubmit= (e) => {
    ...

    }

    render(){
     <Pickers onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>}
```

Comment: the same one which is in the question?
Can you please post the complete code of the Parent and Child

Comment: try this:  ' onClick={this.props.onSubmit.bind(this)}`